# DDD consistency check when creating aggregates with relationship to another aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

When creating new aggregate which has a relation to another aggregates, where should I check do relation aggregates exist? Should it be in the application service, or inside factory by some domain service?

```
class ApplicationService
{
   public void CreateNewAr(relationArId, relationArId2)
   {
      var relationAR = _relationArRepository.getById(relationArId);
      if(relationAR == null)
        throw NotFoundException();

       var relationAR2 = _relationAr2Repository.getById(relationArId2);
       if(relationAR2 == null)
        throw NotFoundException();

      var newAr = _newArFactory.CreateFromAr1And2(relationAR.id, relationAR2.id);
      _newArRepository.Insert(newAr);
      _uow.Commit();
  }
}
```

or

```
class NewArFactory
{
   public NewAr CreateFromAr1And2(relationArId, relationArId2)
   {
      var relationAR = _relationArRepository.getById(relationArId);
      if(relationAR == null)
        throw NotFoundException();

       var relationAR2 = _relationAr2Repository.getById(relationArId2);
       if(relationAR2 == null)
        throw NotFoundException();

      var newAr = new NewAr(relationAR.id, relationAR2.id);
      return newAr;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Go for the domain. Factory or not it is another discussion.

Now, did you realize that, if `NewArFactory` is controling a change in the domain, `NewArFactory` is an aggregate?

Remember that the purpose of an aggregate is control the change. It can be a possible implementation detail but not always an aggregate itself needs to be persisted. When you retrieve an aggregate from persistence does not, always, mean that you should have a aggregate table (or splited in several tables). A repository could get the data (i.e. entities - VOs ids) needed to build an aggregate, using the info in persistence, and return it. The aggregate (through aggregate root) controls the change in the entities and then the new state is persisted.

Things in a domain, like in real life, does not appear from thin air. Try to understand what is happening. A car is assembled, a product arrives from china into our warehause, a user registered himself in our web app, etc. Then provide a better context to the creation of your domain representation (use case and process involved using domain ubiquitous language). From there; an aggregate will emerge to control the change.

Could be self creation, use another aggregate, etc. Even one aggregate that is not persisted could create an aggregate that is persisted... Uff, this thing get very complex to explain without full real domain context in the table.

Note: No aggregate was harmed nor persisted in the making of this answer.

Comment: So, in case you described, I would need to have relation1-2AR which would have all necesarry information for creation of newAR?

Comment: I'm not describing any particular case. I'm just saying that you should go into domain and remembering you that a "factory" does not have domain context and you should think about what creation means in your domain.